# How force distributed in pure rotation particle by particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, rigid-body-dynamics

We know in pure translation force distributed evenly in each particle on rigid body, so in effect every particle of body moves with same velocity or acceleration in pure translation.

What happened in pure rotation, how force is distributed in pure rotation particle by particle to moves a body in pure rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be any different when rotating except that each particle must be subject to a net force from its nearest neighbours which will produce a centripetal acceleration?
This would mean that particles subject to the largest net force are the ones furthest from the axis of rotation.
If the speed of rotation is too high then the bonds between the particles are not sufficient strong to maintain the circular motion and the [body disintegrates as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs7x1Hu29Wc).
Notice the cracks originating at the edge and propagating within the CD which is made of a brittle material.